# How much time do I need (approximately) to learn ROS and create my own package?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to create my own package  (catkin, etc., + simple URDF model, adding sensors and programming it for autonomous navigation in Gazebo) . I have just started to learn ROS thoroughly. I want to use python programming language to program my simulated robot model.
Just give me advice...
How much time do i need ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344109/how-much-time-do-i-need-(approximately)-to-learn-ros-and-create-my-own-package?/) by [ARS](https://answers.ros.org/users/51475/ars/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A week or two sounds like a realistic period. You already know all you need to do. Before Gazebo, look at stage for a 2d simulation which is much simpler to get running. [Turtlebot simulation](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator/tree/melodic/turtlebot_stage) packages are a good place to start

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2020-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ARS](https://answers.ros.org/users/51475/ars/) on 2020-02-15**:
thank you) It would be good if I had a mentor in robotics , but anyway there are many robotics forums like this one and It's so nice)